# Tensorboad activation values histogram not showing up with Keras Callback

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, histogram, tensorboard

I can't see the histograms of activation values using Tensorboard on Keras.

I am currently using tensorflow 2.0 and I've followed the instructions of the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard) on Callbacks. My callback looks like this:

```py
self.callbacks = [tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=self._log_dir, histogram_freq=1)]

history = self.model.fit(train_X, train_Y,
                batch_size=batch_size,
                epochs=epochs,
                validation_data=(validation_X, validation_Y),
                callbacks=self.callbacks,
                verbose=2
)
```

In this structure, for each layer in Tensorboard I only get histograms of the kernel and biases. Is there something missing here?

Comment: This may have something to do with the way you build your models. When you do `model.summery()`, does it print a bunch of layers or several models?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, it correctly prints the layers. Either way, I left this aside for a while (that explains the absence here k) and will see if the new version of tf presents the same behavior after all this was when tf 2.0 was in alpha phase yet.

Comment: Is this issue solved? I'm using TF 2.2 and seem to have the same issue, where weights histograms are present but there is no activation histogram.